# MongoDB Broken Index?

Tags: mongodb

When running the below query: I get back 45 results:

```
{
    nid: {$in: [20,38,70,93,129,132,138,140,143,145,148,149,152,153,154,156,159,160,163,165,166,169,170,171,173,174,176,187,201,204,206,207,209,212,213,215,216,217,236,269,297,345,348,358,370]}               
}
```

When adding the below index to the collection, I get back 2-3 results (randomly let me add):

```
{
   "nid": NumberLong(1),
   "blacklist": NumberLong(1),
   "uid": NumberLong(1) 
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: what are you using to find that query?  Just `db.<collection>.find(<query>);`?

Comment: Correct. I also just tested { nid: 20} (which I know exists and is the correct type) and it returns nothing found.

Comment: I'd suggest testing to see whether the field is null.

Comment: Haha even stranger, there are 92 items in the collection, when running an $exists: false for nid 20, I get back 45 results!

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: I am currently using version 2.4.8

Comment: Even stranger, MongoDB claims it's returning back 45 results, but only geting 2-3. I'm baffled!

Comment: And when I put an index on just the nid field, and hint it, it works.

Comment: Does it say anything about using `it` to show more results?  Also, how did you create the indexes?

Comment: Used both rockmongo (php client), and SHELL, same result.

Comment: Can you post the text of your shell session? This should include creations of documents, initial search, index creation and follow-up search.